# Intellij's Kotlin Compiler "Target VM version" options are confusing

Tags: kotlin, intellij-idea, jvm, version, target

In the IntelliJ IDEA (Community 2021.1) Settings for the Kotlin Compiler, there's a "Target JVM version" menu with the following confusing options: 1.6, 1.8, 9, 10, 11, 12, 13, 14, 15, 1.6.

Are these in chronological order?

Why are there two 1.6's?

Which one is the latest?

Why don't these match the JVM versions [here](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Java_version_history)?

[image]

[image]

Answer (score 2, accepted):

> Are these in chronological order?

yes, going down. (in the second image, I guess not)

> Why are there two 1.6's?

there aren't, it's a 1.6 and a 1.8, and one is probably from a different java compiler producer

> Which one is the latest?

14. [edit: as of today, 16]

> Why don't these match the JVM versions here?

Likely because it is hard to support every version of java that is released.

Comment: Duplicate versions is a bug: https://youtrack.jetbrains.com/issue/KTIJ-914